# Cordova application throws exception in Netbeans

Tags: jquery, cordova, netbeans

I am writing a tic-tac-toe as my first cordova application with netbeans.

I am using jQuery Mobile and I've designed the rough UI.

Here is the source for the UI :

```
<!--
                        Menu Page
-->
<div data-role = "page" data-theme="b" id="MenuPage">
    <div data-role = "header" data-theme="b">
        <h2 class = "Title">Tic-Tac-Toe</h2>
    </div>
    <div data-role = "main-page" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical">
            <a href="#BoardPage" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Single Player</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Multi Player</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Leader Board</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="b">About</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="b" id="btnExit">Exit</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!--
                        Board Page
-->
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="BoardPage">
    <div data-role="main-page" data-theme="b" id = "tabHolder">
        <div data-role="content">
            <center>
                <div class="ui-grid-b" style="position: absolute; top: 38%; width:100%; margin-left:-1em">
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                        <a data-role="button" id="b1"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                        <a data-role="button" id="b2"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                        <a data-role="button" id="b3"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                        <a data-role="button" id="b4"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                        <a data-role="button" id="b5"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                        <a data-role="button" id="b6"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                        <a data-role="button" id="b7"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                        <a data-role="button" id="b8"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                        <a data-role="button" id="b9"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've an exit button there, and I want to exit the application on clicking that button.

My Code :

```
<script>
    $(document).on('pageinit', '#MenuPage', function(events){
        $(document).on('click', '#btnExit', function(event){
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        });
    });
</script>
```

In response I get the following exception in netbeans :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'exitApp' of undefined
```

I've tried googling this, but nothing seem'd to work.

Looking for some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this before script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

If it still fails,  try this

```
navigator.device.exitApp();
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script> worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Are  you clicking the exit button as soon as you see the app on your mobile?
You need to wait for the **deviceReady** event before calling the **exitApp** method
What you can do is Display the menu after the device ready event is fired. e.g

```
<style>
   #MenuPage {
    visibility:hidden;
   }
<style>
<script>
document.addEventListener("deviceready",displayMenu,false);
function displayMenu () {
  alert("Displaying Menu...");
  document.getElementById("MenuPage").style.visibility="visible";
}
</script>
```